# CoreBluetooth DiscoveredPeripheral callback stops after sometime?

Tags: ios, multithreading, xamarin.ios, ibeacon, core-bluetooth

Let me explain the scenario. I am searching for a Beacon using the iPhone. When the beacon is discovered I am sending the "RSSI" value received to a web server periodically (1 second duration). I am doing this by starting a timer when I receive the "DiscoveredPeripheralCallback". Although the below method is continuously getting called initially, once the timer is instantiated this gets stopped and only the timer is executing now. I guess something related to threading is causing the issue.

However if I comment out the timer everything is working fine and I am getting continuous callbacks on the delegate method, but adding a timer and calling an API inside that is causing some issues.

```
    [Export("centralManager:didDiscoverPeripheral:advertisementData:RSSI:")]
    public override void DiscoveredPeripheral(CBCentralManager central, CBPeripheral peripheral, NSDictionary advertisementData, NSNumber RSSI)
    {


         Console.WriteLine("METHOD - 1");
        StartTimer();
        string DeviceName = peripheral.Name;
        discoverdBeacon.AddRawRSSI(RSSI.DoubleValue);
    }
```

Below is the timer method on which I am calling an API.

```
private static void StartTimer()
    {
        // Create a timer with a one second interval.
        if (rssiTimer == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Timer Created");
            rssiTimer = NSTimer.CreateRepeatingScheduledTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0), async delegate
            {
                Console.WriteLine("METHOD - 2");
                var result = await SendBeaconDataToServer(179, 0, -81);
                Console.WriteLine("Result = " + result);
            });
            rssiTimer.Fire();

        }

    }
```

//API method

```
public static async Task<String> SendBeaconDataToServer(int majorId, int loopId, double rssiValue)
    {

        List<Peripheral> beaconsArray = new List<Peripheral>();
        Peripheral item = new Peripheral();
        item.major = majorId; //Keep major values in the range of 178-181
        item.minor = loopId;//Keep minor value as zero for now.
        item.rssi = rssiValue;
        beaconsArray.Add(item);



        BeaconInfo info = new BeaconInfo();
        info.Panic = true;
        info.TagType = true;
        info.TagID = 101;
        info.Anchors = beaconsArray.ToArray();

        var result = await SharedWebClient.Instance.PostUserDetailsDataToServer(info, null);
        return result;


    }
```

Comment: This is likely an issue with Xamarin rather than CoreBluetooth. I don't know much about Xamarin, but if you suspect it to be a threading issue why don't you try and run the timer on a different thread instead? Or preferably, don't run a timer at all. I would consider doing all of the logic in the didDiscoverPeripheral method instead and just check against a timestamp if it is time to upload data. For example, in your upload function, set a timestamp every time you send the event. Then in the callback check if more than 1 second has passed since last upload. Btw 1 second sounds very aggressive.

Comment: @Anton Yes 1 second is too much, I removed the timer and checked it then also this is happening. For some reason when the API is called the DiscoveredPeripheral call back stops.

Comment: Have you turned off the [duplicate filtering option](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbcentralmanagerscanoptionallowduplicateskey?language=objc)?

Comment: @Anton No I have set it to true.